Why does linux hangs when I try to return to a session started via gdm from /dev/tty64?
Recently I experimented with changing the maximum number of tty's on the system from 63 to 128. I was successful in doing this, and now I'm running into a very strange problem.
I'm running gdm on /dev/tty1 and an Xfce4 session through it (running on /dev/tty2). I also have getty running on /dev/tty63 and /dev/tty64
The problem is that when I run the chvt 2 command from tty63 (previous MAX_NR_CONSOLES specified in include/uapi/linux/vt.h), everything switches successfully and I can use Xfce4. But if I run chvt 2 from tty64, the system freezes (no kernel panic) and I can't use mouse/keyboard/other input devices (upd: when I replug keyboard it starts working). Funny enough, when you execute session binary via strace -f everything starts working fine (switching from 64 to 2 tty works).
The problem occurs exclusively when using gdm in Xorg/Wayland sessions. When using a different display manager/manual start everything works fine.
My question is: what could be going wrong? Why when switching to the second tty from any other tty that is <=63 everything hangs? Who to blame? Which syscall/software?

Hmm, some program needs a 6-bit terminal number. The 63-64 boundary hints at 0-63. Try using tty62 and tty63
